# Are there sets in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, data-structures, set

I need a collection that is like a set. Basically I'm scanning a long string and adding words to the collection but I want to be able to detect when there are duplicates.

If sets aren't available, what's the most efficient way of doing this in Ruby? Brownie points for example code.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002237):

```
a = [ "a", "a", "b", "b", "c" ]
a.uniq  #gets you   ["a", "b", "c"]
a.uniq.uniq! #gets you nil (no duplicates :)
```

Comment: Is there something similar that tells me that there are duplicates in the array? Or does uniq have any return value?

Comment: uniq: Returns a new array by removing duplicate values in self. uniq!: Removes duplicate elements from self. Returns nil if no changes are made (that is, no duplicates are found).

Answer (score 75):

There is a Set class in ruby. You can use it like so:

```
require 'set'

set = Set.new

string = "a very very long string"

string.scan(/\w+/).each do |word|
  unless set.add?( word )
    # logic here for the duplicates
  end
end
```

Although, I'm wondering if you would want to count the instances in that case the following example would be better:

```
instances = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = 0 }

string.scan(/\w+/).each do |word|
  instances[word] += 1
end
```

Comment: On Ruby 1.9 and up you don't have to `require 'set'` anymore, it's already there. Also, when you do `my_set.concat [1,2,3]`
the things you add to the set will be cast to another `Set`

Comment: @Julik, you totally still have to `require 'set'`.